# Solving a linear model for a known value of y in R

Tags: r, lm, predict

I have a series of x and y values that I've used to build a linear model.
I can use predict() to find a value of y from a known value of x, but I'm struggling to calculate x from a known value of y.  I've seen a few posts that talk about using the approx() function, but I can't figure out how to implement it for my use case.  The idea is to write a function that takes a numerical value of y as an input and returns the expected value of x that it would correspond to, ideally with a prediction interval, eg "The expected value of x is 38.90, plus or minus 0.7", or something like that.

Here's my data:

```
> dput(x)
c(4.66, 5.53, 5.62, 5.85, 6.26, 6.91, 7.04, 7.32, 7.43, 7.85, 
8.1, 8.3, 8.34, 8.53, 8.69, 8.7, 8.73, 8.76, 8.96, 9.06, 9.42, 
9.78, 10.3, 10.82, 10.98, 11.07, 11.09, 11.32, 11.75, 12.1, 12.46, 
12.5, 12.99, 13.02, 13.28, 13.43, 13.96, 14, 14.07, 14.29, 14.57, 
14.66, 15.21, 15.56, 15.97, 16.44, 16.8, 17.95, 18.33, 18.62, 
18.92, 19.49, 19.9, 19.92, 20.14, 20.18, 21.19, 22.7, 23.25, 
23.48, 23.49, 23.58, 23.7, 23.83, 23.83, 23.97, 24.05, 24.14, 
24.15, 24.19, 24.32, 24.62, 24.9, 24.92, 25, 25.06, 25.31, 25.36, 
25.86, 25.9, 25.95, 25.99, 26.08, 26.2, 26.27, 26.39, 26.5, 26.51, 
26.68, 26.78, 26.82, 26.92, 26.92, 27.05, 27.05, 27.07, 27.32, 
27.6, 27.77, 27.8, 27.91, 27.96, 27.97, 28.04, 28.05, 28.15, 
28.2, 28.28, 28.37, 28.51, 28.53, 28.53, 28.66, 28.68, 28.72, 
28.74, 28.82, 28.83, 28.83, 28.86, 28.89, 28.91, 29.04, 29.2, 
29.35, 29.4, 29.42, 29.48, 29.53, 29.65, 29.67, 29.69, 29.7, 
29.72, 29.93, 29.97, 30.03, 30.08, 30.09, 30.11, 30.18, 30.62, 
30.66, 30.78, 31, 31.32, 31.43, 31.47, 31.69, 31.96, 32.33, 32.5, 
32.5, 32.58, 32.7, 32.92, 33.2, 33.6, 33.72, 33.77, 33.95, 34.02, 
34.08, 34.42, 34.79, 34.91, 34.99, 35.08, 35.15, 35.49, 35.6, 
35.6, 35.74, 35.8, 36.05, 36.17, 36.3, 36.37, 36.84, 37.31, 37.95, 
38.75, 38.78, 38.81, 38.9, 39.21, 39.31, 39.5, 42.68, 43.92, 
43.95, 44.64, 45.7, 45.95, 46.25, 46.8, 49.08, 50.33, 51.23, 
52.76, 53.06, 62)
> dput(y)
c(11.91, 13.491, 13.708, 13.984, 14.624, 15.688, 15.823, 16.105, 
16.387, 17.004, 17.239, 17.498, 17.686, 17.844, 17.997, 18.044, 
18.003, 18.191, 18.332, 18.25, 18.778, 19.237, 19.693, 20.177, 
20.441, 20.876, 20.512, 20.894, 21.493, 21.539, 21.951, 21.763, 
22.498, 22.451, 22.744, 22.785, 23.409, 23.314, 23.408, 23.567, 
23.849, 23.978, 24.472, 24.678, 25.236, 25.547, 25.676, 26.81, 
26.83, 27.275, 27.331, 27.844, 28.009, 28.244, 28.497, 28.555, 
29.067, 30.412, 30.788, 30.965, 31.058, 31.423, 31.346, 31.118, 
31.252, 31.258, 31.399, 31.605, 31.552, 31.881, 31.822, 31.91, 
32.333, 32.174, 32.222, 32.704, 32.445, 32.557, 32.993, 32.845, 
32.997, 32.909, 32.911, 33.121, 33.191, 33.156, 33.426, 33.332, 
33.52, 33.526, 33.697, 33.379, 33.849, 33.726, 33.538, 33.885, 
33.961, 34.284, 34.208, 33.896, 34.278, 34.355, 34.276, 34.267, 
34.399, 34.507, 34.492, 34.531, 34.695, 34.642, 34.872, 34.772, 
34.813, 34.942, 34.883, 34.948, 34.719, 34.983, 34.99, 35.136, 
35.007, 34.026, 35.148, 35.201, 35.459, 35.418, 35.236, 35.411, 
35.459, 35.5, 35.665, 35.724, 35.636, 35.667, 35.747, 35.788, 
35.882, 35.9, 35.83, 36.106, 36.029, 36.364, 36.358, 36.517, 
37.005, 36.74, 36.963, 36.634, 37.04, 37.48, 37.581, 37.78, 37.686, 
38.262, 37.998, 37.986, 38.498, 39.296, 38.467, 38.779, 38.885, 
38.72, 39.038, 38.932, 39.719, 39.654, 39.367, 40.072, 39.707, 
39.742, 39.919, 40.054, 40.189, 40.197, 40.154, 40.383, 42.146, 
40.595, 40.971, 41.441, 41.964, 42.328, 42.463, 42.627, 42.633, 
42.721, 42.786, 42.857, 45.318, 45.665, 46.406, 46.335, 47.663, 
47.181, 48.074, 48.109, 49.931, 50.377, 51.053, 52.451, 53.004, 
65.889)
> model <- lm(y ~ poly(x,3,raw=TRUE))
> model

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE))

Coefficients:
            (Intercept)  poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)1  poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)2  poly(x, 3, raw = TRUE)3  
              6.6096981                1.4736619               -0.0238935                0.0002445
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have fitted a low order polynomial in ordinary form (`raw = TRUE`), you can use `polyroot` to directly find `x` given `y`.

```
## pc: polynomial coefficients in increasing order
solvePC <- function (pc, y) {
  pc[1] <- pc[1] - y
  ## all roots, including complex ones
  roots <- polyroot(pc)
  ## keep real roots
  Re(roots)[abs(Im(roots)) / Mod(roots) < 1e-10]
}

y0 <- 38.9  ## example y-value
x0 <- solvePC(coef(model), y0)
#[1] 34.28348

plot(x, y, col = 8)
lines(x, model$fitted, lwd = 2)
abline(h = y0)
abline(v = x0)
```

[image: root]

To get an interval estimate, we can use sampling methods.

```
## polyfit: an ordinary polynomial regression model fitted by lm()
rootCI <- function (polyfit, y, nSamples = 1000, level = 0.05) {
  ## sample regression coefficients from their joint distribution
  pc <- MASS::mvrnorm(nSamples, coef(polyfit), vcov(polyfit))
  ## for each row (a sample), call solvePC()
  roots <- apply(pc, 1, solvePC, y)
  ## confidence interval
  quantile(roots, prob = c(0.5 * level, 1 - 0.5 * level))
}

## 95% confidence interval
rootCI(model, y = y0)
#    2.5%    97.5% 
#34.17981 34.38828
```

Comment: This solution is a bit more complex than some of the others below, but I've selected it as the best one because it solves both parts of the problem, not just the first. (i.e. it gives a confidence interval as well as a predicted value of x).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `optim`:

Predict the y values given x:

```
pred_y <- function(x)predict(model, data.frame(x))
pred_y(x = 10)
[1] 19.20145
```

Now to predict x given y, we do:

```
pred_x <- function(y) optim(1, \(x) (y-pred_y(x))^2, method='BFGS')[[1]]
pred_x(19.20145)
[1] 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The `uniroot` function is intended for this type of problem.

```
#coefficients for the model
coeff <- c(6.6096981, 1.4736619, -0.0238935, 0.0002445)


#define the equation which one needs the root of
modely <- function(x, y) { 
 # could use the predict function here
   my<-coeff[1] + coeff[2]*x + coeff[3]*x**2 + coeff[4]*x**3
   y-my
}

#use the uniroot functiion
#In this example y=10
uniroot(modely, lower=-100, upper=100, y=10)

$root
[1] 2.391022

$f.root
[1] -1.208443e-08

$iter
[1] 10

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

In this case for y=10, x = 2.391022

Comment: Can the $estim.prec value here be used to calculate a prediction interval?

Comment: Yes, from the help: "estim.prec gives an approximate estimated precision for root."  And the tolerance is adjustable in order to obtain a more precise value of the root.

Comment: Thanks Zheyuan Li, I came to the same conclusion.